# Relative consistency of $\mathsf{ZFC}-$Ext$+\neg$Ext+"every set has a unique powerset"

Tags: logic, alternative-set-theories

Let $T$ be the $\mathcal L_\in$-theory whose axioms are the axioms of $\mathsf{ZFC}$, with extensionality replaced by its negation, and an additional axiom specifying that every set has a unique powerset, formally

$$\forall x\forall y\forall z((\forall v(v\in y\leftrightarrow v\subseteq x)\land\forall w(w\in z\leftrightarrow w\subseteq x))\rightarrow y=z),$$

where $a\subseteq b$ is to be expanded as an $\mathcal L_\in$-formula in the usual way.

Is $T$ consistent relative to $\mathsf{ZFC}$? The motivation for this question comes from the fact that $V\setminus V_\omega$ models $\mathsf{ZFC}$ with extensionality replaced by its negation, but powersets are not unique: for every $x\in V\setminus V_\omega$ both $\mathcal P(x)^V\setminus V_\omega$ and $\{s\in V\setminus V_\omega\mid s\setminus x\subseteq V_\omega\}$ fulfill the definition of powerset.

Comment: ZFC with urelements?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how urelements are added to ZFC precisely, can you elaborate? @Noah

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Noah commented. ZFC + Ur-elements is known to be consistent relative to ZFC. It is usually referred to by "[ZFA](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/ZFA)", i.e. ZF with atoms. In one formulation of that theory ONLY empty objects violate Extensionality! So we do have many empty objects (the Ur-elements). However all non-empty sets are extensional! That is, "No distinct non-empty sets are co-extensional (i.e. have the same elements)". Clearly this theory satisfy all of your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I'll post this as a separate answer, because I'm not quite sure of it, although I'm sure of the above accepted answer.

I'll present a rather trivial way of getting $ZFA$ from $ZF$.

Define an alternative membership relation $\in^*$ as:

$y \in^* x \iff y \in x \wedge  [x \text { is an initial segment of } N \to y \neq max(x)]$

where naturals are defined after Zermelo as the empty set or the iterated singletons of the empty set. An initial segment of N is a finite set of naturals closed under predecessor function for non zero elements; and $max(x)$ is the maximal element of $x$.

So in English: $y$ is an alternative member of $x$ is the same as the epsilon member of $x$ if $x$ is not an initial segment of $N$, but when $x$ is an initial segment of N then $y$ is an alternative member of $x$ only if $y$ is a non-maximal member of $x$.

This way we'll have the empty set $0$ being $\in^*$ empty, and also the set $\{0\}$ set being $\in^*$ empty as well. So we have a single violation of Extensionality. I think it is provable in $ZF$ that all rules of $ZFA$ would hold for this new membership relation $\in^*$ over any domain of $ZF$. Also you can get $ZFCA$ from $ZFC$ under the same interpretation.